# Difference between Search and Incremental Exports?

Tags: zendesk-api

**Incremental Exports:**

I query at a certain time for all records which have changed since a specific time. I would personally use the max updated_at timestamp in my database.

https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/incremental_export

**Search:**

I can query a certain endpoint/table for all tickets which have been updated since the max updated_at timestamp in my database.

https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/search

```
path='/api/v2/search.json', query='query=type:ticket updated>=2019-06-10T00:00:00Z'
```

It seems like both of these methods achieve the same goal, but I want to be certain that I choose the right one and that there are no caveats or issues I will run into later.

I assume that if I keep track of the max update timestamp that I have already retrieved, then I can always pull new/changed records >= from that timestamp (and only have minor duplication that I need to address from records with the exact same timestamp). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between ***Search*** and ***Incremental Export*** is ***Query***.

But according to you *start_time* in **Incremental Export** and *country=US&toll_free=true* in **Search**  both are same but actually *NOT*.

Because query is **checking the availability of something,** which is actually performing by any search query but in **start_time** that is not query because you are just pointing a starting point you have no concern what the values is coming. But in query you have concerns, because you want "***That is the value which I want***"

Hope so you are getting my point and clearing your doubt.

Comment: Yep - thanks I went with incremental exports and it has been working quite well. I actually implemented something very similar for a few other REST APIs as well, using the zendesk one as inspiration.